# Why doesn't this program reverse a string?

Tags: c

I am learning C. I wrote the following program to try and reverse a user-input string. However, it doesn't work. I'd like to know why.

Here is the code with comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char* normal; // initialize the original string
    printf("Give me a word.\n"); // ask for user input
    scanf("%s", &*normal); // retrieve input, set variable
    int n = strlen(normal); // retrieve length of string
    char reversed[10] = {0}; // declare reversed string

    // for loop starting from n length, decrementing by one
    for(int i = n; i >= 0; i--) { 
    /* for i in the original string, the reversed string
       equals n minus i, to reverse the string one by one */ 
       normal[i] = reverse[n - i];
    }

    // print the newly reversed string
    printf("%s\n", reversed);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @yellowantphil     Just noticed that and deleted my comments

Comment: Shouldn't it be `i = n-1` in the for loop?

Comment: Adam: You are setting the elements in `normal` to the data in `reverse`, but you never set `reverse`. I assume that `reverse` and `reversed` are the same thing, with just a typo, but it's filled with zeros.

Comment: `normal[i] = reverse[n - i];` Is this not arse over tit

Comment: What output _do_ you get?

Comment: @Adam apparently you are new to SO, did you take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Your Idea is almost correct except because

1. You are copying the `'\0'` to the begining of the `reversed` string.
2. You are `scanf()`ing into an invalid pointer
3. You are doing the assignment in reverse, i.e. Instead of

   ```
   normal[i] = reversed[n - i];
   ```

   it has to be

   ```
   reversed[n - i - 1] = normal[i];
   /*               ^ you should start at the n - 1 position, and '\0'
    *                 should be at position n.
    */
   ```

Try this instead

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char normal[100]; // initialize the original string
    char reversed[100]; // declare reversed string

    printf("Give me a word.\n"); // ask for user input        
    if (scanf("%99s", normal) != 1) // retrieve input, set variable
        return -1;
    int n = strlen(normal); // retrieve length of string

    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
        /* for i in the original string, the reversed string
         * equals n minus i, to reverse the string one by one 
         */
        reversed[n - i - 1] = normal[i];
    }
    reversed[n] = '\0';

    // print the newly reversed string
    printf("%s\n", reversed);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You dereference a wild pointer:

```
char* normal; // uninitialized, points to random location

scanf("%s", &*normal);    // write to random location (at best)
```

The `&*` has no effect by the way. Anything else that happens from hereon in is undefined as a result.

To fix this you could write:

```
char normal[10];
scanf("%9s", normal);
```

Then your loop goes on and copies from `reverse` (which is blank) into `normal`. You probably meant to copy from `normal` into `reverse`. The assignment operator is `destination = source` .

Finally, your loop (if you made that fix) starts from `normal[strlen(normal)]` which is the null terminator. You need to check `n > 0` and then start from `i = n-1` .

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 30

int main() {

    char normal[SIZE+1], reversed[SIZE+1];
    int n = 0, i = 0;

    printf("Give me a word.\n");
    fgets(normal, SIZE, stdin);
    //^ Reads in the text
    n = strlen(normal);


    for(i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)
       reversed[n-i-1] = normal[i];
    //^ Changed, also note that the index starts with 0

    reversed[n] = '\0';
    //^ End string

    printf("%s\n", reversed);

    return 0;
}
```